# pandas groupby when count is zero and how to include zero value in result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, count

Please consider any solution without usage of *pivot_table()* or *unstack()*

For the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Mason', 'Ali', 'Si', 'Pedram'],
    'continent': ['Europe', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia'],
    'blood_type': ['AB', 'O+', 'AB', 'AB']
})
```

Which is:

```py
    name     continent  blood_type
0   Mason    Europe     AB
1   Ali      Asia       O+
2   Si       Asia       AB
3   Pedram   Asia       AB
```

The following groupby count:

```py
df.groupby(['continent', 'blood_type']).count()
```

Will produce:

```py
                           name
continent   blood_type  
Asia        AB             2
            O+             1
Europe      AB             1
```

Instead, how can I include zero value count like the table below? (by not using *pivot_table* or *unstack*)

```py
                           name
continent   blood_type  
Asia        AB             2
            O+             1
Europe      AB             1
            O+             0
```

Comment: what do you mean by pure pandas? pivot and unstack are pandas methods

Comment: OK, right. To avoid any confusion I removed 'pure pandas'. I don't want to use unstack stack method. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `pandas` 0.25 (or 0.24.2, not sure now), if you groupby a Category (`pd.Categorical`), it will show all values in the final count.

```
df.groupby([pd.Categorical(df.continent), 'blood_type']).count().fillna(0)

                   name  continent
       blood_type                 
Asia   AB           2.0        2.0
       O+           1.0        1.0
Europe AB           1.0        1.0
       O+           0.0        0.0
```

Comment: Hi, it does work for 0.24.2 indeed but it does return NaN which is fine anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @pedrum take a look at the `fillna(0)` at the end ;p